# how to add custom menu item for existing photos app in ipad/iPhone

Tags: objective-c, ios

Is there feasibility to add a custom menu item like 'upload this pic to my app'. In inbuilt photos app when a photo is selected a menu is displaying with 'Email photo', 'Assign to Contact', 'Use as Wall paper','Tweet'... . In that list of items I want to add a option 'Upload to XXX app'. Is it possible. Please help me.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot change the behavior of in-built apps. Imagine how long that list would go if that was possible.

Comment: @user1179590 see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application

Comment: okay but then this isn't what he is asking for. You can register your app to open certain file types when encountered on the web, but you cannot change the behavior of other apps to follow the same thing.

Comment: I was responding to his (now deleted) comment.

Comment: The Mail app having additional option like 'Open in ...". I understand this is by UIDocumentInteractionController. Like this is t not possible for photo App.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can definitely create your own menu with the "Upload to XXX app". You don't need to modify the inbuilt photo app to do so.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this isn't what OP was asking for.

Comment: @ JustSid He wants to modify the inbuilt photo app, well he can't ,the only way is to create a different menu for uploading the photos